# cognos monitoring

Tags: cognos

Does cognos 8 have an api which can be queried to find out:

1. the last time a scheduled report has run
2. was it successful?
3. if not, what caused it to fail?

it would be preferable for the api to be web based. I have read about a JMX interface but documentation was lacking.

Answer (score 0):

Cognos 8 has an option to enable logging to an Audit Database.  The database would then be queryable for details such as when a report ran, what parameters were used, and what if any errors there were.

[Link to IBM site for setting up the logging database.](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/c8bi/v8r4m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.cognos.inst_cr_winux.8.4.1.doc/inst_cr_winux_id18024creat_log_db.html)

[Link to IBM site for setting up the connection to the database.](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/c8bi/v8r4m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.cognos.inst_cr_winux.8.4.1.doc/inst_cr_winux_id18117SetUptheDatabaseClientforaLoggingD.html)

Basically you create a compatible database with the proper settings, then tell Cognos how to connect to it, then the next time Cognos services start up, it will automatically create necessary tables for logging and begin populating them automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, to accomplish this in the API fashion, you want to use Cognos SDK.  SDK allows you to query scheduling and history associated with report runs and see if the request was completed or failed.  If failed, you will see History associated with the failure much like you see in the Cognos Administration section when you go to look at the failed runs.

This is a good place to start to look at a sample:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21343791